Coordinate system of a screenshot from Google Earth
I have received a transport assessment for an intersection (swept paths created in CAD) and learnt the way it was created was by drawing an line in Google Earth - a known measurement (for example 20m) then taking a screenshot including that line and pasting that screenshot to AutoCAD and scaling the image based on the known measurement (20m Line ), noting this screenshots also have a pin on them with the lat, long in the image.
I cannot just ask better information, I have to work with what I am given.
Is there any Google Earth expert here who knows which projection is applied when measuring distances on Google Earth, would it be the relevant UTM zone?
Obviously when I try to bring the referenced info based on the base point (pin point), the information is rotated and doesn't align. I am assuming is due to the projection system. I could try to reference the images in CAD based on the right projection if I knew.
Any ideas?

I doubt there's any chance of accurately georeferencing a screenshot generated as described.

I didn't read the post but: https://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2015/10/google-earth-measures-distances.html

Google Earth shows the planet as a sphere, and can compute distances between points across large distances that would span many UTM zones. Distances computed across that kind of distance would be very wrong compared to distances computed along a great circle of the sphere.
Google Maps (2d, via the web) uses the "Spherical Web Mercator" projection which approximates the Earth as a sphere with a radius of 6378137 metres to transform lat-long to X-Y. I suspect Google Earth is using that radius to compute distances along great circles. Some sample points on Google Earth and their reported distances (eg from N pole to S pole) should confirm this.
